# How to create a SharePoint list item based on two Array Variables

Tags: arrays, sharepoint, power-automate

This is related to power Automate.
I have two array variables here.
Say Array `A=[1,2,3]` and Array `B=["abc","xyz","ghj"]`
Now I need to
run flow and create a SharePoint list item based on this two arrays.
Three SharePoint list items will be created based on this two arrays look like this.

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |
| 3 | ghj |

Please give suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the exact same amount of values, you could Create a Compose that does

```
Length(variables(‘A’))
```

And then store the Compose output to a variable that is an integer.

Create a Do Until

And loop through the count of that variable

For the Create Item,

You can do

```
Variables(‘A’)[0]
```

But instead of the 0 you put the current looped variable